# How to Merge Arrays with WHERE Clause?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to add 2nd array into 1st array where [ myid ] matches.

**1st Array**

```
Array
    (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [myid] => 70
                    [realname] => Kishore
                    [full_name] => Kishore Chandra
                    [category] => professional
                    [firm_name] => Yes
                    [designation] => Mechanical
                    [address] => Dwarakanagar 5th lane
                    [city] => Vishakhapatnam
                    [email] => yesapps.india@gmail.com
                )

            [1] => Array
               (
                    [myid] => 75
                    [realname] => Vinod kumar
                    [full_name] => Kishore Chandra
                    [category] => professional
                    [firm_name] => 
                    [designation] => 
                    [address] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [email] => vinod.k.alluri@gmail.com
               )
     )
```

**2nd Array**

Need these projects to be added into **Array 1**

```
Array
        (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [myid] => 70
                        [projects] => 20
                    )

                [1] => Array
                   (
                        [myid] => 75
                        [projects] => 43
                   )
         )
```

I have tried to Merge Array's but no use, i am getting 2 more objects in to this array

I hope my requirement is clear and readable, if not please mention in comment so i could explain it more.

The answer can be in codeigniter also i am using Codeigniter framework

Comment: Can you show table structure on which you want to put where clause?

Comment: It is not where clause actually :) I am expecting result where "myid" matches to "myid" in both arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that you want the result array to be merging the projects to your first array

you want the result set to be like this

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [myid] => 70
            [realname] => Kishore
            [full_name] => Kishore Chandra
            [category] => professional
            [firm_name] => Yes
            [designation] => Mechanical
            [address] => Dwarakanagar 5th lane
            [city] => Vishakhapatnam
            [email] => yesapps.india@gmail.com
            [projects] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [myid] => 75
            [realname] => Vinod kumar
            [full_name] => Kishore Chandra
            [category] => professional
            [firm_name] => 
            [designation] => 
            [address] => 
            [city] => 
            [email] => vinod.k.alluri@gmail.com
            [projects] => 43
        )

)
```

so try this code

```
foreach($b as $key => $val){        
    if(isset($a[$key]) && $a[$key]->myid == $val->myid){
        $a[$key]->projects = $val->projects; 
    }       
}
```

if converted the stdArray to Array 
json_decode($a,TRUE)
and json_decode($b, TRUE)

```
$a = Array
(
        0 => Array
            (
                'myid' => 70,
                'realname' => 'Kishore',
                'full_name' => 'Kishore Chandra',
                'category' => 'professional',
                'firm_name' => 'Yes',
                'designation' => 'Mechanical',
                'address' => 'Dwarakanagar 5th lane',
                'city' => 'Vishakhapatnam',
                'email' => 'yesapps.india@gmail.com',
            ),

        1 => Array
           (
                'myid' => 75,
                'realname' => 'Vinod kumar',
                'full_name' => 'Kishore Chandra',
                'category' => 'professional',
                'firm_name' => '',
                'designation' => '',
                'address' => '',
                'city' => '',
                'email' => 'vinod.k.alluri@gmail.com'
           )
 );

 $b = Array ( 0 => Array(
                    'myid' => 70,
                    'projects' => 20
                    ),
            1 => Array(
                    'myid' => 75,
                    'projects' => 43
                    )
            );

foreach($b as $key => $val){        
    if(isset($a[$key]) && $a[$key]['myid'] == $val['myid']){
        $a[$key]['projects'] = $val['projects']; 
    }       
}
print_r($a);
```

**NOTE:**

1. $b is the 2nd array
2. $a is the 1st array

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object at line 2 from your code

Comment: did you changed the $b to 2nd array variable name and $a to 1st array variable name

Comment: yes i did !  and it is confirm that both arrays are having the same data as i have mentioned above in the question

Comment: You can even give me the answer for JSON array.. i have actually json_decode those both arrays

Comment: foreach($data2 as $key => $val){
    if(isset($data1[$key]) && $data1[$key]->myid == $val->myid){
        $data1[$key]->projects = $val->projects;
    }
}   Error Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: make it as `json_decode($a, TRUE)` this will make it as stdArray to Array

Comment: Now no error :) Tell me fast how to pull out a final array from this?

Comment: No change in array's both are printing same old results

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $array){
  foreach($array as $key2 => $value){
    $results[$key]['myid'] = $value;
  }
}

foreach($array2 as $key => $array){
  foreach($array as $key3 => $value){
    $results[$key3]['projects'] = $value;
  }
}
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Assuming that you want combine two array which 'myid' is match.

Comment: Yes you are rite but i am getting the second array result when i follow the above code you have posted..  Can you please make a sample PULCKER for this answer

Comment: what will be in $a, $b?  If its is $array1 and $array2 it is not working.

Comment: If there is any solution with codeigniter even please send it i am using that framework now in this project.

Comment: $a and $b , you have to pass two parameters in function.

Comment: I know i have to pass two parameters, but what are those parameters .. i have passes array1 and array2 in to that but did't work.

Comment: now I actually understand your problem, you combine two array which key is same.

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at line 2 from your code -- error displayed several times as loop